# SpriteKit: rotation without friction

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

Is there a way to make a sprite rotate after contact with other sprites but without having frictional forces applied to it?

If i set

```
sprite.physicsBody.friction = 0.0; 
sprite.physicsBody.allowsRotation = YES;
```

no rotation occurs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a body to rotate upon sliding contact with other bodies, some friction is necessary. (Just like in real-world physics!) Do you want friction to cause rotation, but exhibit frictionless behavior once it's rotating? If so, rereading the previous sentence should give a clue to the answer: you need to change the friction coefficient after the body starts rotating. Setting a [contact delegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsContactDelegate_Ref/Reference/Reference.html) gives you an opportunity to make this change. It's also good for just about any other case where you want to "fudge" the results of a collision after it occurs, such as re-setting the body's velocity to a predetermined value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manage the rotation by yourself, you can detect the collision with the delegate and the apply angular impulse like this
    [sprite.physicsBody applyAngularImpulse:0.05];

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I'm not getting the point but what you seem to want to do is really just:

```
sprite.zRotation = 1.0;  // Note: zRotation is in radians
```

Or use SKAction `rotateToAngle:duration:` if you want the rotation to occur over a period of time.

Comment: I want the friction to cause the rotation but don't affect the sprites speed.

Comment: hmmm i don't believe that's possible